# module 'numpy' has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, python-3.5, python-import

When importing sklearn datasets eg.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "numbers.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
  File "/anaconda2/envs/numbers/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/anaconda2/envs/numbers/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/anaconda2/envs/numbers/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/anaconda2/envs/numbers/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 93, in <module>
    from . import numerictypes as nt
  File "/anaconda2/envs/numbers/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/numerictypes.py", line 86, in <module>
    import numbers
  File "/Users/airocoop/repos/Numbers/numbers.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
  File "/anaconda2/envs/numbers/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .base import load_breast_cancer
  File "/anaconda2/envs/numbers/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/base.py", line 20, in <module>
    from ..utils import Bunch
  File "/anaconda2/envs/numbers/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse import issparse
  File "/anaconda2/envs/numbers/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    from numpy.random import rand, randn
  File "/anaconda2/envs/numbers/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/__init__.py", line 143, in <module>
    from .mtrand import *
  File "numpy.pxd", line 87, in init mtrand
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'dtype'
```

I am not sure why I get this

I don't get this error when running things from a jupyter notebook, which is also weird. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Seems like you have inconsistent versions of sklearn and numpy.

Comment: How, *exactly* is this being run?

Comment: It is also possible that the `numbers` environment inherited a different version of numpy from anaconda2 base  environment

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am running the command `$ python numbers.py` from a terminal on mac OS, in the numbers environment. runing `$ conda list` gives me (among other things):
`{ numpy                     1.16.2           py36hacdab7b_0 },`
`{ numpy-base                1.16.2           py36h6575580_0},` 
`{ python                    3.6.8                haf84260_0 },` 
`{ scikit-learn              0.20.2           py36h27c97d8_0}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured this out. The answer is that the file I was running was named `numbers.py`. This screws the whole thing up. If you have this problem check to make sure you don't have a file in the directory called `numbers.py`

Easy way to check is move the file with the import statement to a different directory and try running it.

Comment: I had this issue as well but the file causing the problem was called "signal.py" in my case. Rather than saying "make sure you don't have a file in the directory called numbers.py", you must say something like "check any recent .py file you've added and try changing its name". When I had the issue I read your answer several times but I didn't pay much attention to it because I didn't have any file called "numbers.py"...

Answer (score 6):

Broken installation.

Do this:

1)

```
conda install numpy=1.13
```

or 2)

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

Comment: what if the OP isn't using pip to manage this particular dependency? pip was notoriously problematic when trying to install numpy/scipy on windows, requiring at one point having people install a fortran compiler. I hear the situation has gotten a lot better, but a lot of people use `conda`. Note, OP is working with `/anaconda2/envs/numbers/lib/python3.5`

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the replies. Your right I am using conda but no luck with trying:
`$ conda remove -n numbers numpy`
`$ conda install numpy`
(numbers is my env)
also tried the $ conda install numpy=1.13