# module 'numpy' has no attribute 'object'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, kubernetes, dockerfile

I am getting below error when running `mlflow app`

> raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute " AttributeError:
> module 'numpy' has no attribute 'object'

Can someone help me with this

Answer (score 30):

Since version 1.24 of numpy, `np.object` is deprecated, and needs to be replaced with `object` (cf. [numpy release notes](https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations)).

You either need to update this in your code, or another package you're using needs to be updated (not possible to answer without more information).

One (dirty) workaround for now would be to fix your numpy version to the last version still supporting `np.object` with `pip install numpy==1.23.4`

Answer (score 14):

Try :

```
pip3 install numpy==1.23.5
```

I was facing same issue with  numpy 1.24.2

Answer (score 5):

Try to use simple "monkey path". Add line like

```
np.object = object
```

or

```
np.int = int
```

in case *module 'numpy' has no attribute 'int'*

```
np.float = float
```

*module 'numpy' has no attribute 'int'*

```
np.bool = bool
```

and so on... (if problem with last Numpy versions)

Comment: sorry vegarus it worked in jupyter notebook but how to modify the object if I run pyscenic from shell? (base) pc@bioinfo:~$ np.object = object    
np.object: command not found

Comment: I haven't got the slightest idea about Pyscenic. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `numpy.object`:

you should use `object` or `numpy.object_`.

Answer (score -2):

The Python "AttributeError module 'numpy' has no attribute 'object'" occurs when we have a local file named `numpy.py` and try to import it from the `numpy` module. To solve the error, make sure to rename any local files named `numpy.py`.

**Another way:**  Check that the file you are running was named `numpy.py`. If you have this problem check to make sure you don't have a file in the directory called `numpy.py`.

In most cases, `rename your project local file numpy.py and delete numpy.pyc if it exists`, then your project file script will run without an attribute error.

Easy way to check is to move the file with the import statement to a different directory and try running it.

Please check whether you have installed a newer pip updated numpy version.

Also check the similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55108902/module-numpy-has-no-attribute-dtype) for more information.